# Running shell_exec in background on windows using php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, shell-exec, laravel-controller

I have controller like this

```
public function test()
{
  shell_exec("node  node-server\socket.server.js > node.log");
  return 1;
}
```

but when I run this controller with ajax, status is (pending) and I want show me 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it

```
popen('start /B node-server\socket.server.js > node.log', "r");
return 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

ajax is waiting the ending of node js query, you have to send it to process in background by adding

```
shell_exec("node  node-server\socket.server.js > /dev/null &");
```

Comment: I want add log on  'node.log'